# get a return also if a part of a sentence is copied instead of the whole sentence c#

Tags: c#, string, class, notifications, clipboard

**WHAT DO I WANT?**

I want that if you take a part of the question sentence that you get the same return than if you copy the entire sentence. I was already watching the StartWith method but I do not know how to use it. Does anyone have a solution for this? This is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
namespace test
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            //Invoke a clipboard monitor
            [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);
            private IntPtr _ClipboardViewerNext;

            //Make some global variables so we can access them somewhere else later
            //This will store all Questions and Answers
            //In here will be the Questions and Answers
            List<question> questionList = new List<question>();

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Set our application as a clipboard viewer
                _ClipboardViewerNext = SetClipboardViewer(this.Handle);

                //Add question/answer to list
                question newQuestion = new question("When a computer is being assembled, which action can be taken to help eliminate cable clutter within a computer case?", "Install a modular power supply.*");
                questionList.Add(newQuestion);
                newQuestion = new question("vraag2", "antwoord2");
                questionList.Add(newQuestion);
                newQuestion = new question("vraag3", "antwoord3");
                questionList.Add(newQuestion);
            }

            private void getAnswer(string clipboardText)
            {
                //Loop through all questions and answers
                foreach (question q in questionList)
                {
                    //If we have found an answer that is exactly the same show an Notification
                    if (q._question == clipboardText)
                    {
                        showNotification(q._question, q._answer);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void showNotification(string question, string answer)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = question;
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = answer;
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
                Clipboard.Clear();
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                {
                    const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
                    if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD) {
                        getAnswer(Clipboard.GetText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want to return the answer of a question if the question contain some of the words you have copied?

Comment: yes that is what i want

Comment: Well. There is a good trick. I'll explain it for you in an answer.

Comment: if you want to explain it please!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

First remove any 'space' from the questions and store them in a separate field. For example:

```
string question="how are you today";
string questionWithNoSpace=question.Replace(" ","");//Which makes the question like this:"howareyoutoday".
```

Now get the question from the clip board and split in by 'space' like this:

```
string userQuestion ="how are you";
list<string> parts=userQuestion.Splite(" "); //Which returns a list containing {"how","are","you"}
if (parts.All(a=>questionWithNoSpace.Contains(a)))
        {
            return "Blah! that is your question";
        }
```

Remember to convert everything into lower case

Comment: thats not want because i have more than 100 questions in a list. i want a more efficient way to do it maybe someone knows a StartWith method